# Merging a Dataframe with a column of times and index with dates to another Python Dataframe with same date index

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have a python dataframe with a column of temperatures and times and index of dates and I want to add in another Dataframe that only has times but has the same date indexes as the first dataframe. I want to insert the new dataframe as new rows that have the same date index but adds a row at the new time.

For simplicity Im going to show a snippet of each dataframe:

```py
data1 = [[78,'6:53','6/15/2023'],[79,'7:53','6/15/2023'],[80,'8:53','6/15/2023']]
df1=pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Temperatures','Time','Dates']).set_index('Dates')
print(df1)

data2 = [['7:51','6/15/2023'],['8:51','6/15/2023']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Time','Dates']).set_index('Dates')
print(df2)
```

What Id like to do is merge them so it looks like this:

```py
data = [[78,'6:53','6/15/2023'],[np.nan,'7:51','6/15/2023'],[79,'7:53','6/15/2023'],[np.nan,'8:51','6/15/2023'],[80,'8:53','6/15/2023']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Temperature','Time','Dates']).set_index('Dates')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a temporary datetime column, concat the dataframes, sort it and remove the temporary column:

```py
df1['tmp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.index + ' ' + df1['Time'])
df2['tmp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.index + ' ' + df2['Time'])
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values(by='tmp')
df.pop('tmp')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           Temperatures  Time
Dates                        
6/15/2023          78.0  6:53
6/15/2023           NaN  7:51
6/15/2023          79.0  7:53
6/15/2023           NaN  8:51
6/15/2023          80.0  8:53
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = [[78, '6:53', '6/15/2023'], [79, '7:53', '6/15/2023'], [80, '8:53', '6/15/2023']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Temperature', 'Time', 'Dates']).set_index('Dates')

data2 = [['7:51', '6/15/2023'], ['8:51', '6/15/2023']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Time', 'Dates']).set_index('Dates')

# Merge the dataframes based on the index
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)

# Sort the dataframe based on the index
df = df.sort_index()

# Reset the index to keep the 'Dates' column as a separate column
df = df.reset_index()

# Print the resulting dataframe
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        Dates  Temperature   Time
0  6/15/2023         78.0   6:53
1  6/15/2023          NaN   7:51
2  6/15/2023         79.0   7:53
3  6/15/2023          NaN   8:51
4  6/15/2023         80.0   8:53
```